# ¿Como puedo unir varias respuestas http.get y actualizar ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tengo dentro d un controlador varias llamadas `$http.get('/...')` que obtienen los datos correctamente.

```
$scope.results = [];
$http.get('/call1').then(function(response){
    proccess(response);
});
$http.get('/call2').then(function(response){
    proccess(response);
});
$http.get('/call2').then(function(response){
    proccess(response);
});
```

Los datos que retornan son del tipo:

```
// call 1
{items:{1:{id: 1, title: "Título",…}, 2:{id: 2, title: "Título",…},…}}
// call 2
{items:{1:{id: 10, title: "Título",…}, 2:{id: 20, title: "Título",…},…}}
// call 3
{items:{1:{id: 100, title: "Título",…}, 2:{id: 200, title: "Título",…},…}}
```

En la función que procesa, al ser todas las estructuras iguales es sencilla:

```
function proccess(response){
    $scope.results = response.items;
}
```

El `ng-repeat`

```
<div data-ng-repeat="item in results">
    {{item.id}}
</div>
```

Y en esta parte es donde me encuentro el problema.

En teoría estoy intentando que el `ng-repeat` se actualice con los nuevos datos conforme los va obteniendo.

He probado con `extend`, `concat`, `merge`, `push`... y siempre me los sustituye o me lanza errores por consola y ando un poco atascado con este tema.

¿Como se deben unir las respuestas para que actualice el `ng-repeat` conforme va recibiendo los datos?

*PD.: Cualquier duda comenten y actualizo*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema mas importante es que en el `ng-repeat` utilizas `items` como fuente de datos y no `results` (lo que estableces en `$scope.results`). Asi como esta, va a hacer el bucle por `$scope.items` (que no se ve donde lo defines).

```
<!-- aqui abajo, cambia items x results -->
<div data-ng-repeat="item in results">
    {{item.id}}
</div>
```

> He probado con extend, concat, merge, push... y siempre me los sustituye o me lanza errores por consola y ando un poco atascado con este tema.

Quiza no usaste `concat` correctamente. Recuerda que no modifica el array actual sino que retorna uno que tiene la suma de ambos arrays por lo que necesitas reasignarlo.

La forma correcta para que funcion es asi:

```
function proccess(response){
  $scope.results = $scope.results.concat(response.items);
}
```

Comment: He corregido lo de la variable `items`. Discúlpame, ha sido un error al redactar la pregunta. Pruebo la forma que propones y te comento.

Comment: Todo correcto ahora. Gracias.